# Swift ScrollView In UITableViewCell not scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I am new to swift and am trying to add a `UIScrollview` to a custom `UITableViewCell`. I can't seem to get the scrollview to scroll in the simulator though.  I have tested both vertical and horizontal scrolling.

Here is the code for my custom `UITableViewCell`

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var winLoseValueLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newTotalLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playersLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playersScrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.playersLabel.text = nil
        //self.playersScrollView.contentSize.height = 1000
        self.playersScrollView.contentSize.width = 1000

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func addLabelToScrollView(str : String) {
        if self.playersLabel.text == nil{
            self.playersLabel.text = str
        }
        else{
            self.playersLabel?.text = self.playersLabel.text! + "\n\(str)"
        }
    }
}
```

My playersScrollView outlet has been properly connected to the `scrollview` in my storyboard. As far as I can see from all of the tutorials and sources online, I should just have to set the contentSize width or height (larger than the view area) to get it to scroll, which I have done in the awakeFromNib function.

Any ideas why this is not working in the simulator?  Secondly, ideally I would like to have a vertical scrolling scrollview in the table cell, but I thought that the table view's vertical scrolling might have been interfering with the scrollview, so I changed it for horizontal scrolling for testing, which also didn't work.

Can you have a vertical `scrollview` in a vertically scrolling `UITableView`, or will the table view scrolling interfere too much with the `scrollview`?

Comment: What might be happening is that your UITableView is "stealing" the touch events from you tableViewCells. The approach of adding a UIScrollView inside a UITableViewCell is not encouraged, since we have what is called the Responder Chain, that determines the object that will deal with the pan gestures. This is something expected, and the guidelines advise to avoid this situation as a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that the constraints on my playersLabel, which is a subview of playersScrollView, was the culprit, although I am not sure why.  I adjusted the constraints on the label and that allowed the horizontal scrolling to work.

The vertical scrolling still did not work, so I had to override the touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods in the scroll view so I could disable/re-enable the scrolling of the table view.